# Merging two html documents and add a shadow effect to the first document

Tags: html, css

I need to merge two html documents and add a shadow effect to the first html document, without actually changing the the html.

That's not very clear, let me show it via code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>Put some stuff in here</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<div id="myseparatorstuffgoeshere"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>Put some stuff in here</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, you'll notice that I have the div in the middle with the id "myseparatorstuffgoeshere". THAT'S the only place that I'm allowed to add the shadow effect.

What have I tried/thought of trying:
1) Using gradient

```
min-height: 1.5rem;
max-height: 1.5rem;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(black, white);
background: -o-linear-gradient(black, white);
background: linear-gradient(black, white);
```

2) Box-shadow: inset...this just shows up solid black for me:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 200px 300px 100px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 20px 30px 100px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 20px 30px 100px #000000;
-o-box-shadow: inset 0px 20px 30px 100px #000000;
```

Is there another approach to do here? I'd like to just use the gradient, but I don't know how to "angle" the left and right sides that the box-shadow does by default.

Here's the fiddle that I've been using: http://jsfiddle.net/andegre/ejepu755/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem.  I'm not sure this is the solution you want, but without direct control of the other elements, it's a little difficult.  I suggest making an element that kind of fakes the top element with a large height to accommodate not knowing how tall it should be like so:

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.documentx {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.separator {
    min-height: 6rem;
    max-height: 6rem;
}

.gradient-in {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 #000;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 1000rem;
    margin-top: -1000rem;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.gradient-out {
    min-height: 1rem;
    max-height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="documentx">
    <span>This is the body of document #1</span>
</div>
<div class="separator">
    <div class="gradient-in"></div>
    <div class="gradient-out"></div>
</div>
<div class="documentx">
    <span>This is the body of document #2</span>
</div>
```

Notice that I had to also add a reset for the body to avoid an odd gap at the top of the first document.

Alternatively, you can use a negative spread.  I was slower than Danny Klatt to get the solution posted, but here is a version of my example using it:

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.documentx {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.separator {
    min-height: 6rem;
    max-height: 6rem;
}

.gradient-in {
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 2.5rem -1.5rem #000;
    height: 0;
    min-height: 1000rem;
    margin-top: -1000rem;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.gradient-out {
    min-height: 1rem;
    max-height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="documentx">
    <span>This is the body of document #1</span>
</div>
<div class="separator">
    <div class="gradient-in"></div>
    <div class="gradient-out"></div>
</div>
<div class="documentx">
    <span>This is the body of document #2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I went with!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but you can modify how a box-shadow element works (having it start inside of the element and then flow outwards).

Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ejepu755/4/

In your actual code snippet you could just add it to #myseparatorstuffgoeshere with margins if need be.

```
.documentx {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px -6px #000000;
}

<div class="documentx">
    <span>This is the body of document #1</span>
</div>

<br />

<div class="documenty">
    <span>This is the body of document #2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was just working out this alternative too.  Decreasing the spread with a negative value is a great idea.